# transfer List item from One list to another list in same site using NINTEX WORKFLOW

Tags: updatelistitems, update, nintex

how i can Get records from a list of columns and column transfer it to another list using the nintext workflow

Comment: i do create nintex workflow and use action  with query list and Build string and Update item

Comment: i will do get record of column on list and update other list column  what i do